# as3 - differene between public and public static?

Tags: actionscript-3

So I heard static can make it so other classes can access that class's variables.

But what difference does it make when you use public or public static?

Don't they both allow it for other classes to access that class's variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already an accepted answer that is unfortunately completely wrong on practically every single points. We can't let people discover that post and be misguided so badly. This answer will attempt to correct all those mistake for future reference.

"Public is the visibilty of the file". Wrong. Public is an access modifier that tell how a class, member, method can be accessed externally. The mention of "file" here is wrong.

"static allows access to the file's variables, functions, etc". Wrong. static is only an access modifier that makes a variable or method belong to the class not the instance. It has no effect on how those variables/methods are accessed. For example a static private variable cannot be accessed externally. Here again the mentioned "file" is wrong and has nothing to do here.

"Being public essentially means etc ..." . Gonna let that one slide. public is an access modifier that means the variable/method can be accessed externally.

"static means it can be used by other files". Absolutely not. the only purpose of static is to make a variable/method belong to a class not an instance. It has no effect on how external classes/instance can access it. For example a static private cannot be accessed by any other classes. Here again the term "file" is misused and has nothing to do with coding.

Now the correct answer:

public used in a class means variable/method that belong to an instance of that class.

public static in a class means variable/method that belong to the class.

For example in a class A with public method named "instanceMethod" and public static method named classMethod you access them like this:

```
var instance:A = new A();
instance.instanceMethod()//calling an instance method
//the "public function instanceMethod belong to instances of A

A.classMethod()// this is a static public method that only the class itself can call
//trying to do instance.classMethod() would throw an error.
//trying to do A.instanceMethod() would throw an error.
```

EDIT:

To answer your question we have to talk about 'scope' but that subject is too vast to be answered here. I'll give you some quick guidelines.

The term 'scope' is used in all programming languages, it refers to which object is currently referenced in the code. Inside instance methods, the scope refers to the instance itself. Inside static methods the scope is the class itself. Inside instance methods the 'this' keyword is implicit and refers to the instance. In static methods there's no 'this' that can be used. You can in theory create an unlimited number of class A instances and each one of them will have its own 'instanceMethod' to call. On the other hand all static property/methods are unique to the class and there's only one of them at all time since all classes in any given project are unique.

Concrete example: the Array class. You can create a new array like this:

```
var myarray:Array = [];
//then use the instance method/property
//those method/property are unique to that instance you just created
myarray.push("hello");
//calling 'push' adds 'hello' to the 'myarray' instance only so 'push' is unique to that instance
//Array class defines also some static property like NUMERIC
myarray.sort(Array.NUMERIC);
//that property NUMERIC is unique to the class and since the class is unique too there's only one Array.NUMERIC that can exist.
```

Comment: What if the instance is removed? Would the instance method still work? Also for the class method, what happens if during the game, the properties of some of the variables changed. If that instance of the class was removed. Would the class have saved the changed variables or reset to it's written state on the code?